# Is it possible to display CustomAttributes in Exchange Online

Tags: exchange, exchangeonline

We have migrated from Exchange 2016 to Exchange Online.

In the mailbox view in EAC for both 2016 and Online you can Add/remove columns to customize your view. However it seems to be limited in Exchange Online compared to that in 2016.

In our local AD we use a number of *CustomAttributes* for our users which are synced to AAD/Exchange, and in 2016 those can be chosen as columns to be displayed, also it's possible to display the *HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled* property. In Exchange Online however I can't choose those columns. But if I double click a mailbox/user in Exchange Online I can directly see the checkbox for the *HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled* property and clicking on **More options...** I can see that the *CustomAttributes* are visible to Exchange.

I've tried with both the old and the new EAC view for Exchange Online and neither of them allows me to choose those columns to display.

With Powershell and the `Get-Mailbox` cmdlet I can get the mailboxes matching the desired criteria, but the new `Get-EXOMailbox does` not seem to expose these attributes.

`Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled -eq 'True'}`

`Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.CustomAttribute7 -eq 'Staff'}`

The best would be to be able to display these columns so our support-staff can sort on them if they need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked on my side, yes, we cannot add columns for CustomAttribute in Exchange Online. The old Get-Mailbox cmdlet will retrieve all  of the mailbox properties. The new Get-EXOMailbox, by default, will only retrieve a minimum set of properties. To include additional properties to the minimal output you can use the Properties parameter. So for your issue, we should refer to the followings:

Get-EXOMailbox -Properties CustomAttribute7 | Where{$_.CustomAttribute7 -eq 'exo'} | select UserPrincipalName

https://www.easy365manager.com/get-exomailbox/

If the issue has been resolved, please mark the helpful replies as answers.

Comment: Thank you. Tried Get-EXOMailbox | Select-Object -Properties * and got the same limited output, so I thought it didn't expose those properties at all.